# Auto email people from VBA module

Tags: excel, vba

I want to read a list of tasks assigned to various people and send them reminder regarding tasks allocated to them based on a list of email addresses placed in the spreadsheet range, however, ignoring those people who have already been sent reminders. I have this code so far.

```
Sub datesexcelvba()
    Dim myApp As Outlook.Application, myMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim duedate1 As Date
    Dim duedate2 As Long
    Dim todaydate1 As Date
    Dim todaydate2 As Long

    Dim x As Long
    'from what row the data needs to be read from
    lastrow = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For x = 4 To lastrow


        'READS THE DUE DATE THEN TURNS INTO LONG
        duedate1 = Cells(x, 6).Value
        duedate2 = duedate1
        'PUTS DUE DATE LONG TEXT IN BELOW CELL
        Cells(x, 12).Value = duedate2

        'following just reads the due date, then turns it into a text format to read
        todaydate1 = Date
        todaydate2 = todaydate1
        'PUTS ABOVE DATE INTO CELL BELOW
        Cells(x, 13).Value = todaydate2

        Set myApp = New Outlook.Application
        Set myMail = myApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

        'the following code is talking about finding the reminders if the deadline has been reached
        If duedate2 - todaydate2 = 2 Then
        'if email already sent, reads this box and should exclude these emails
            If Cells(x, 11).Value <> "Yes" Then
            'finding the email address to send to
                 myMail.To = Cells(x, 10).Value
            End If
        End If

        With myMail
            .Subject = "Safety Action Reminder"
            .Body = Cells(x, 7).Value
            'following line to see if email looks good
            .Display
            '.send
        End With

        'IF REMINDER NEEDS TO BE SENT, IT WILL AUTO FILL THE CELL WITH CODE BELOW
        'Cells(x, 7) = "Yes"
        'BELOW CODE JUST CHECKING THAT THE DEADLINE AND REMINDER ARE 2 DAYS APART
        Cells(x, 8).Value = duedate2 - todaydate2

    Next
    Set myApp = Nothing
    Set myMail = Nothing

End Sub
```

Many Thanks

Comment: If you indent your code life will be so much easier ...

Comment: Puting `else` is completely different to `elseIf` or `if`. You are not testing anything. What happens is that when `duedate2 - issuedate2 <> 2` it will continue with the  `else`.

Comment: So I need to change the Else to elseIf you're saying? Along with anything else?

Comment: We don't know if your list is sorted and you don't capture the the mailed status of a recipient.  If a recipient can be found multiple times anywhere on the list then you must have a way of determining if a mail has been sent or not. Where do you do that?  If the list is sorted such that a recipient can be found in an uninterrupted block and nowhere else then you don't need to record the status, rather, you can limit your primary for loop to the count of unique names and use the count of repeat names to increment your row index inside a block of a repeating name.

Comment: Well the list will be from date of issue for a specific task. So for instance 4 separate people may have 5 jobs each. Some people will have tasks listed together other times all over the list. Just differs. Then when a task is completed will delete that whole row and move everyone up one. So at the moment it just needs to read the email sent row and see a yes or not, send when there is nothing then add a Yes to block out that email for next time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   ...

   Set myApp = New Outlook.Application
      Set myMail = myApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

  'finding the email address to send to
  'HERE IS THE MODIFICATION I ADDED
  If Cells(x, 11).Value <> "Yes" Then
   myMail.To = Cells(x, 10).Value

  With myMail
    .Subject = "Safety Action Reminder"
    .Body = Cells(x, 11).Value
    'following line to see if email looks good
    .Display`enter code here`
    '.send
  End With

    ...
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks

Comment: Then would you please edit your answer and emphasize that? I will remove all these comments as soon as you are done fixing it.